# Accessing Plone 4 portlet's assignment context from Renderer instance

Tags: python, plone, portlet

I would like to make a context portlet for Plone4, which will be then added to certain folders and visible in their respective subfolders. However, no matter where the portlet is shown I would like to access portlet's assignment context (where it was put in the first place) in the Renderer's instance.

```
class Assignment(base.Assignment):
    ...

class Renderer(base.Renderer):

    def base_folder(self):
         # self.context is the current context.
         # but how to access the folder, to which the portlet has been assigned?

...
```

Searched for the "assignment" context in the self.manager and self.data, but has not found anything suitable.

There could be some workarounds: like searching the path from self.context up to the folder with portlet or saving some information into Assignment's instance upon portlet creation, but I wonder if there is some direct way?

Comment: No direct solution, but some pointers http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/portlets/tips.html#checking-if-a-certain-context-portlet-is-active-on-a-page

Comment: Thank you. Seems like I will implement aq chain search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with the following because I wanted to provide a link directly to the portlet's settings dialog. I think the value of context at the end of the function is the object you want:

```
def settingsUrl(self):
    # this is odd... should be much more straightforward?
    # also, this is pretty slow.
    manager = self.manager
    context = self.context
    assignment = self.data

    allAss = []
    while not assignment in allAss:
        pam = getMultiAdapter((context,manager), IPortletAssignmentMapping)
        allAss = pam.values()
        if assignment in allAss:
            break

        if IAcquirer.providedBy(context):
            context=aq_parent(aq_inner(context))
        else:
            context = context.__parent__

    return '%s/++contextportlets++%s/%s' % (context.absolute_url(), 
                                            manager.__name__,
                                            assignment.__name__)
```

Upd. 2014: it also looks like one might be able to piece together this information from the portlet renderer's `__portlet_metadata__` property, which has the keys `key` (location of assignment), `category` (e.g. 'context'), `manager` (e.g. 'plone.rightcolumn') and `name`.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. Especially IAcquirer condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Renderer(base.Renderer):

    def your_method(self):
        assignment_context_path = self.__portlet_metadata__['key']
        assignment_context = self.context.restrictedTraverse(assignment_context_path)
```